# FluentValidation check start date greater than end date

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have this C# code with FluentValidation rule which check start date should be less than end date. When I run to put start date greater than end date, it should show error "End date must after Start date".

```
        RuleFor(r => r.StartDate)
       .NotEmpty()
       .WithMessage("Start Date is Required");

        RuleFor(r => r.EndDate)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End date is required")
            .GreaterThan(r => r.StartDate.Value)
                            .WithMessage("End date must after Start date")
            .When(m => m.StartDate.HasValue);
```

In my model, these 2 properties defined as below:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Based on your other questions, are you trying to surface these errors client side?

Comment: Yeah. In my client side I'm using .net core views with tag helper

Comment: Built-in client-side support is limited; It doesn't work when you try to compare against other POCO values. I'd also suspect that usage of the When option also will stop it working. The client validators resolve the rules to data-attributes which end up being literal values, not references to other form field values.

Comment: So should I move those validation to domain layer instead? If can I would like to put all my input type validation using fluent validation

Comment: Those validation rules will still execute as part of the middleware validation that occurs when you submit the request; you'll just need to handle the model state error as you see fit. You will get the key/property name so you can match them to a specific validation span, I have done it in the past. You could probably write your own client validator for a cleaner implementation. For lambda validator conditions I generally delegate to my service layer where I have a secondary validation invocation. I do the latter to allow my service to be reused elsewhere whilst still retaining validation.